# Click event supressed by Jquery Accordian

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

Folks, 
I have accordian panel which contains a checkbox in its header :

```
 <div id="accordion">
   <h3><a href="#"><input type='checkbox' id='chkbox'/>First header</a></h3>
   <div>First content</div>
    <h3><a href="#">Second header</a></h3>
   <div>Second content</div>
</div>
```

now when i click on checkbox, the click event is suppressed by jquery using event.preventDefault. Consequently I can not get checkbox state changed. I tried following trick but no luck:

```
$("#accordion").accordion();

$('#chkbox').live('click',function(){
   var checkbox = $(this).find(':checkbox');
   checkbox.attr('checked', !checkbox.attr('checked'));

});
```

Please help!!
see the code http://jsfiddle.net/teBfb/1/
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing with

```
.attr('checked', !$checkbox.attr('checked'));
```

should work. Which means your selector is busted. Any reason why you're using $ signs in variable names? It might confuse jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

You could use stopPropagation so your checkbox click event doesn't go up the chain.

```
$("#accordion h3 input").click(function(e) { 
    e.stopPropagation(); 
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/teBfb/6/

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to update the jsfiddle with my change. Try the new one in my post.

Comment: Sorry @flynfish your solution works with click event. but i have to use live since, all my checkbox are created on fly. live('click',function... ) is not working...

Answer (score 0):

```
   $(function () {
        $("#accordion").accordion({
            collapsible: true,


        });
    });



    $("#accordion h3 input").click(function (e) {

        var checkedStatus = $(this).prop('checked');
        e.stopPropagation();
         if (checkedStatus) {


           $("#accordion div div").slideUp();

            $(this).parent().next().slideDown();
         }
        else {


             $("#accordion div div").slideDown();

             $(this).parent().next().slideUp();

       }


    });
```

try this